# Flot Graph : Link Zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have two graphs say Graph A and Graph B, Both have same x-axis values i.e date.
So when a user zoom on graph A, is it possible to zoom (re-plot) graph B with the selected zoom range value on graph A

Note: Zooming is done by selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, and in fact that [exact example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/zooming.html) is shown on the [example page](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) for flot.

Check out the source of that example to see the details of how it works.  Essentially, you bind the `plotselected` events on both graph A and graph B, and call the `plot.setSelection(range)` function for the opposite graph in each.  There are more details, but again, it's all in the source there.